# I broke C13, is it serious doctor?

Tags: hardware, electronics

EDIT: I got a good answer on electronics SE, you can check it out [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179716/how-to-replace-a-smd-capacitor-on-a-raspberry-pi).

While desoldering the GPIO, I accidentally broke the capacitor C13 of my raspberry pi model B (2011.12 Rev7).

It is the capacitor between RG3 and the GPIO pins.

Looking up the schematics, it appears this cap is a 10nF cap connected on the 2V5 line to ground, parallel with C15, which is a 10µF.

[image: raspi schematic]

I spent about two hours searching for a similar cap in various salvaged components. I finally found one on an HP dv6000 internal wifi board. (I had to check every value I desoldered, one by one, kinda tedious).

I did not solder it back yet, but i'll soon do.
I also did not tried powering my pi with the cap missing.

I wanted to know if there was any way to know that everything was back into order. What is the exact purpose of that cap, and how can I test that I soldered it correctly ?